# Expression in Hive LIMIT clause

Tags: sql, hive, impala

In Impala, you can do this:

SELECT x FROM t1 LIMIT **cast(truncate(9.9) AS INT)**;

But in Hive, it seems to only take **LIMIT [constant]**.

Is there a way to add expression in LIMIT?

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/impala_limit.html

Comment: No, Hive doesn't support it

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in Hive. As a workaround you can calculate variable in the shell and pass it to the Hive using `--hivevar` variable. [Limit](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-LIMITClause) clause allows only per-calculated variables or constants as arguments:

Demo with variable. You can pass it also as `--hivevar` argument in the hive command line:

```
    hive> set hivevar:limit=10;

    hive> select 10 limit ${hivevar:limit};
    OK
    10
    Time taken: 0.098 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Setting hivevar works for constants, but it doesn't work for expressions, if used in limit clause.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Hive do not calculates them, substituting as is. that is why I suggested to calculate in a shell if it is applicable